# Javascript data structure

Tags: javascript, json

I have a script that I'm working on, this script reads a zip file and extracts the contents of the files inside the zip. What I'm trying to do is send a request to my server in the following format:

```
file0name,contentfile0;file1name,contentfile1;file2name,contentfile2
```

Can someone tell me what type of data structure I should use? Is it a list or a JSON object?

https://jsfiddle.net/ker1w6pb/6/

Comment: json for sure... it can have a list inside it.

Comment: Can you share some more details? I'm interested how you're going to use JavaScript to _"read...and extract the contents"_ of a zip file in client side JavaScript?

Comment: Are you putting content into a string? (confused)

Comment: actually I haven't done that yet for the moment I just created the function that read the files in the zip. I'll share a JSFiddle not that I'm using the JSZip library.

Comment: What you send to the server is a string. How you build and parse it is up to you.

Comment: @torazaburo That was my initial thought too, but then I read this line: _"What i'm trying to do is to send a request to my server in the format:"_ and was confused as Node is already on the server. Why would you have one server read the contents to send to another server? Seemed like an odd case, thus I assumed it was client side?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Since you say "send a request to my server", presumably you are talking about a client-side script, but JS on the client side cannot read a zip or any other file. How you send what to the server is completely up to you. For instance, you could send it as a form-like POST.

Comment: @torazaburo Actualy I'm writing a script to use in my VisualForce page so for the moment I just need to extract the data from the zip file, sending the request to the server is gonna be done later in my Apex code

Comment: Based on your above comment, your question seems really incomplete. You don't have any code examples of what you're tried, you haven't tagged the systems you're using for a better understanding of your setup and you have left out an enormous amount of detail such as that stated in your above comment. I think you need to edit your question into more of a coherent thought. Consider explaining the systems your using, showing the existing code you've tried and what you'd like the final outcome to be.

Comment: @War10ck I know it's because just to make it simple that I only talked about the javascript, In fact it's a SalesForce project and I can't post all my classes and VisualForce Pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you convert your content into a string (which sounds odd to me), you can just POST a JSON data object containing your string:

```js
var postData = [{
  filename: 'file0',
  content: 'content0'
}, {
  filename: 'file1',
  content: 'content1'
}, {
  filename: 'file2',
  content: 'content2'
}];

var postString = postData.reduce(function(previous, current) {
  return previous + current.filename + ',' + current.content + ';';
}, '');

//post(uri, {data: postString});
document.write(postString);
```